# Can I have an MySQL database auto-assign a value to a column after an insert statement?

Tags: mysql, triggers, insert-statement

Given a table employee with columns ID(pk) and name

```
ID|name
--+-----
1 |John
2 |James
3 |Tom
```

Can I do

```
INSERT INTO employee (name) VALUES (Jack);
```

and somehow have the database auto assign the next available ID? Can a trigger do it? If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create your table with an <strike>identity</strike> autoincrement column:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name
(
   id INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
   -- other columns to follow
)
```

Answer (score 2):

You want auto increment column. You can refer to the documentation here:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [AUTO INCREMENT Feature](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html) in My Sql. When you create the table, you can do something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE employee(
 id MEDIUMINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 name CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

Or May be use the [alter table](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html) Query to modify the column `ID` to have auto incremented values