# How to assign sequential value to one column in mysql database?

Tags: mysql

I have one table like this

[image]

and I want to convert it into table like this

[image]

Basically, I want to assign sequential value to column id.
Is there any query for that? 
Also what are the equivalents for rownum in mysql?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I have an MySQL database auto-assign a value to a column after an insert statement?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6614982/can-i-have-an-mysql-database-auto-assign-a-value-to-a-column-after-an-insert-sta)

Comment: Actually I want to do it on existing rows in an existing table. So I assume that this question is different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in one way. Make the `id` column as `PRIMARY KEY AUTO INCREMENT` and then change the data values of all the `1`s with `null` and then try inserting.

```
CREATE TABLE `people` (
     `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     `name` CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
     `profession` CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

And then the SQL like:

```
INSERT INTO `people` VALUES
(null, 'John', 'Engineer'),
(null, 'Ronny', 'Doctor'),
(null, 'Monty', 'Engineer');
```

Comment: is it possible to do it in existing table?

Comment: can you please tell me how to do that?

Comment: You just need to generate the SQL and replace the same values using a text editor. As simple as that. But do you have any code with you?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [AUTO_INCREMENT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html)

```
CREATE TABLE animals (
     id MEDIUMINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     name CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

Answer (score 1):

You would do this by creating a PRIMARY KEY and giving it an AUTO_INCREMENT, like this

```
id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
```